# How to use like in query

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have a problem in sqlite query, I want to use "like" for search, but Xcode shows this error

> "Ambiguous reference to member 'like(_:escape:)'"

Maybe there is something wrong in writing in this way? But I read the GitHub's document of SQLite-Swift.

The example in GitHub is

```
users.filter(email.like("%@mac.com"))
// SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("email" LIKE '%@mac.com')
```

Here is my code

```
import Foundation
import SQLite
import UIKit
class ViewService {

  var database : Connection!

  let inputDetailTable = Table("input_detail")
  let deleteFlag = Expression<Int>("delete_flag")
  let id = Expression<Int>("id")

func selectTableData(date :Date) -> [InputDetail] {

let selectedData = self.inputDetailTable.filter(self.deleteFlag == 0 
&& self.deleteFlag.like("0%"))

}
}
```

Hope somebody could help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your delete flag is an Int.  You can't use "LIKE" on an Int because it pattern matches on a sequence of characters:

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, and MATCH operators
>
> The LIKE operator does a pattern matching comparison. The operand to
>   the right of the LIKE operator contains the pattern and the left hand
>   operand contains the string to match against the pattern. A percent
>   symbol ("%") in the LIKE pattern matches any sequence of **zero or more**
>   **characters in the string**. An underscore ("_") in the LIKE pattern
>   matches any single character in the string. Any other character
>   matches itself or its lower/upper case equivalent (i.e.
>   case-insensitive matching). Important Note: SQLite only understands
>   upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default. The LIKE operator is
>   case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the
>   ASCII range. For example, the expression 'a' LIKE 'A' is TRUE but 'æ'
>   LIKE 'Æ' is FALSE. The ICU extension to SQLite includes an enhanced
>   version of the LIKE operator that does case folding across all unicode
>   characters.

Comment: Really appreciate for your help!The problem is solved,only "string" type have the "LIKE" function,thanks.